# is it possible to emulate a moving point through a polyline?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I'm doing an app with a polyline  and i want to emulate a car moving through the polyline...is it possible? I don't have a gps device, or is it posible to receive coordinates from another android device and use it as a gps? how can I achieve this?

i would like that the green marker would appear to be moving, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> doing an app with a polyline and i want to emulate a car moving through the polyline...is it possible?

Yes possible, you can move a marker between points, look [this](https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689)

> I don't have a gps device, or is it posible to receive coordinates from another android device and use it as a gps? how can I achieve this?

I don't understand what you mean, but

- If you wanna use phone or tablet as a gps device, they have already gps module.
- If you wanna use standalone gps tracker device and send location data to mobile device, AFAIK there is bluetooth gps modules/devices, so you can use it.

**EDIT**

I suggest watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ&nohtml5=False). In this video marker is being moved between two points, so you can move your marker through points of polyline respectively.

Comment: is it possible to animate it through coordinates? i've seen the link that you gave me but i can't quite undestand it...i'm sorry i'm new to android thank you for your help i hope you can help me again

Comment: i can't make it work :( that's the only thing that i miss to finish my app  i'm so desperate i've seen a lot of videos

Comment: whats the problem ? Everything is done to move marker as you wish in that gist.